# How can I refresh the application by clicking on the button?

Tags: c#

I just wanted to ask I have a button in my programme which by clicking on it will generate some images in the form of animation to my output screen.
My problem is while my form is open and the programme is executing, each time I click on the button it just adds more data on top of each other instead of re-run the programme.
Can you please give me any solution to resolve this problem and basically when I click on the button it starts the programme from fresh?

Comment: Please show some code if you can.

Comment: please add some code. The button Event Handler will be helpfull to diagonise your problem.

Comment: Clear all contents (ie previous data) before adding new data.

Comment: Are you asking how to clear graphics from your "output screen"? If so what it is?

Comment: i have basically a series of code which generates continuously images to my output(i don't think the code really will be in your interest). i just want to know how can i add something at the end (or at the beginning) of my button even handler so by clicking on my button it will reset the programme and starts from scratch.

Comment: `i don't think the code really will be in your interest` that is where you are wrong, try to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, pointing to the exact code and spotting the error there is easier than guessing what is wrong from your descriptions, that is why people are `always` encouraged to include code (snippets) that enable your possible helpers to easily reproduce your issue and help fix it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    InitializeComponent();
    //the code you wrote in the button click or if the code is in another button write:
    // button.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work! it will crash the application...

Comment: Did you try it ? Are you using winform ?

Comment: i am making a form, but if i put it at the beginning of my form it will not execute the rest of the application

Comment: What to put in the beginning ????!  It's a button's click event add the these two lines to your button click event

Comment: i understand, but the whole programme basically starts when i press the button. in the other word all my programme is written my button_click

Answer (score 0):

[Control.Refresh Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Refresh the windows on click event.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that?